# Unix Loop a script until there is user input

Tags: linux, loops, unix

I need some clarity if i can carry out a script loop where it will go on endless unless someone hits anything on a keyboard.

I simply want the script to go on the loop switching echo functions until a key is pressed.

I don't really know what else to write or how to explain this simpler.

Here is my script which i think will work well for that.

```
#!/bin/bash
act(){
sleep 1 #delay code to show message
clear 
echo "no action taken" #first message
#some code to skip next line after a set amount of time
read int #read code for user input
act2 #go to next message
}

act2(){
sleep 1 #delay code to show message
clear
echo "still no action taken" #second message
#some code to skip next line after a set amount of time
read int #read code for user input
scan #go back to if statement
}

scan(){
if [ "$int" == "" ] || [ "$int" == 0 ] #scan if input is empty
then
act #load first message
else
echo "action was done" #States that input was not empty
fi
}

echo "Hit enter" #prompt
read int #read empty input
scan
```

Comment: Is it my idea or you should be using a timeout for read?

Comment: Let's wait 5 seconds max for user to give us some feedback: ```read -t 5 variable; echo $variable```. I think this will only work if the user presses _enter_. If you would want to get whatever the user wrote up to that point (even if the user didn't press enter), then I don't think read will suffice.

Comment: @Edmundo use `read -n 1` in a loop and build up the input line yourself. You lose line editing though.

Comment: Thank you @Edmundo for the reply and it actually worked with -t 5.